# How to click_link with no text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

How can I click below link with Capybara's click_link method?

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">
  <span title="Sign out" class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could locate the element using its href attribute:

```
page.click_link('', :href => '/users/sign_out')
```

Note that the first parameter of `click_link` is the links text, id or name. We use '' since the text is blank.

Alternatively, use the find method to find the link using the href attribute (or any other attribute) and then click it.

```
page.find(:css, 'a[href="/users/sign_out"]').click
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `id` to link and use its `id`.

```
click_link('link_id')
```

More info [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#clicking-links-and-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

For the applications, which use `JS` it is useful the following call:

```
find(:css, 'a[href="/users/sign_out"]').trigger('click')
```